# Uncaught Error. java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: react-native, expo, uncaught-exception

I get an error when I wanna run my expo app on metro bundler.
This is the error:

"Uncaught Error. java.net.SocketTimeoutException. failed to connect to exp.host/104.197.216.164(port 443) from ****(port (****) after 10000ms"

I tried different ways.
upgrading expo-cli, downgrading expo-cli, disabling firewall, disabling Antivirus.
didn't solve the problem
Can anyone help?
thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8nXV.png)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, what worked for me is to ensure that my computer is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as my device and that in the network settings on the pc they are in a private network, using these 2 things worked perfectly for me. I hope to see you helped, postscript I do not speak English I hope you can understand me

Answer (score 4):

Connect with USB, turn on USB Tethering and enable developers mode on your android mobile.

Comment: Adding to this to make it work, I entered into the Expo the manual url exp://127.0.0.1:<port number> - so localhost - in my case: exp://127.0.0.1:19000

Comment: `expo start --localhost` then in your mobile device click on manual url and enter the exp link shown in console like `exp://127.0.0.1:19000`

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error, my app would not load. So I changed the network from public to private in 'Windows' and it worked !!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF599.png)

Comment: Your Solutions works on windows `10` and `11`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

none of these things worked for me until I changed the exp://IPGoesHere:1234 to the ip that is shown from my phone wi-fi network

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the PC and the cell phone are in the same Wi-Fi network, it happened to me that I did not have Wi-Fi and was connected from my cell phone with data and the PC with Wi-Fi, I put the Wi-Fi on the cell phone and it worked, it is an option, try .

Answer (score 0):

If you are under WSL2 then you have to run npm start using native windows npm. They have different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: Go,   Setting > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi > click on connected Wi-Fi and simply change public network into private network.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Galaxy S23 Ultra. I've enabled USB Debugging and USB tethering and for running the my app on the developer mode I've used `npx expo start --localhost` and it worked for me. This not related but I also should mention that on Galaxy phone or in general SamSung phones you should also disable "Secure Folder" feature.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above, but what worked for me was to update the Expo CLI and Expo Go, by running:
`npm install -g expo-cli`